# Adding a UIView as a first run view only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios4, launch

I would like to add a Welcome view to my app which describes the instructions etc.

I would like this to appear only once when the app is first launched... then with subsequent launches go to my app's main view... which is a navigation controller.

What is the best way to track launches/ implement this idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root controller of a navigation controller (the view controller that is normally visible as first one), activate a modal controller with those initial instructions with `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

You probably want to call it from within `viewWillAppear:`. Do not animate presenting of modal view controller (otherwise you see what's below), but animate when dismissing it - it looks really elegant.

Use UserDefaults to store the information that it had already been shown, and do not show it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefault is made exactly for these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with JustSid.  In my app, I set a NSUserDefault value for that use and then turned it off when the viewDidLoad.  The app checks for the value but, unless the app is uninstalled, will not fire the message.